# How to merge object properties of the same class together via LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, unit-of-work

Say I have a class, I want to select multiple objects of it but create one unified object in the end. This is because of the requirement for the collection properties of the object to be combined.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Nozomi.Base.Core;

namespace Nozomi.Data.Models.Currency
{
    public class Currency : BaseEntityModel
    {
        public Currency(ICollection<Currency> currencies)
        {
            if (currencies.Any())
            {
                var firstCurr = currencies.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstCurr != null)
                {
                    // Doesn't matter...
                    Id = firstCurr.Id;
                    CurrencyTypeId = firstCurr.Id;
                    CurrencyType = firstCurr.CurrencyType;
                    Abbrv = firstCurr.Abbrv;
                    Name = firstCurr.Name;
                    CurrencySourceId = firstCurr.CurrencySourceId;
                    CurrencySource = firstCurr.CurrencySource;
                    WalletTypeId = firstCurr.WalletTypeId;
                    PartialCurrencyPairs = currencies
                        .SelectMany(c => c.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        .ToList();
                }
            }
        }

        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public long CurrencyTypeId { get; set; }
        public CurrencyType CurrencyType { get; set; }

        public string Abbrv { get; set; } // USD? MYR? IND?

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long CurrencySourceId { get; set; }
        public Source CurrencySource { get; set; }

        // This will have a number if it is a crypto pair to peg to proper entities
        public long WalletTypeId { get; set; } = 0;

        public ICollection<PartialCurrencyPair> PartialCurrencyPairs { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Abbrv) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) && CurrencyTypeId > 0 && CurrencySourceId > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what a PartialCurrencyPair is:

```
namespace Nozomi.Data.Models.Currency
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Partial currency pair.
    /// </summary>
    public class PartialCurrencyPair
    {
        public long CurrencyId { get; set; }

        public long CurrencyPairId { get; set; }

        public bool IsMain { get; set; } = false;

        public CurrencyPair CurrencyPair { get; set; }
        public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**So basically, if you want to make EURUSD, you'll have to take two currencies to form a pair. A CurrencyPair is made up of two PartialCurrencyPairs. The reason why we can have many EUR or many USDs is that they come from different sources.**

Here's what a CurrencyPair is:

```
public class CurrencyPair : BaseEntityModel
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public CurrencyPairType CurrencyPairType { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Which CPC to rely on by default?
        /// </summary>
        public string DefaultComponent { get; set; }

        public long CurrencySourceId { get; set; }
        public Source CurrencySource { get; set; }

        // =========== RELATIONS ============ //
        public ICollection<CurrencyPairRequest> CurrencyPairRequests { get; set; }
        public ICollection<WebsocketRequest> WebsocketRequests { get; set; }
        public ICollection<PartialCurrencyPair> PartialCurrencyPairs { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid()
        {
            var firstPair = PartialCurrencyPairs.First();
            var lastPair = PartialCurrencyPairs.Last();

            return (CurrencyPairType > 0) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(APIUrl)) 
                                          && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultComponent))
                                          && (CurrencySourceId > 0)
                                          && (PartialCurrencyPairs.Count == 2)
                                          && (firstPair.CurrencyId != lastPair.CurrencyId)
                                          && (!firstPair.IsMain == lastPair.IsMain);
        }
    }
```

I have an IQueryable to combine into one single currency.

Code with comments (The comments basically tells you what I'm trying to achieve.

```
var query = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Currency>()
                .GetQueryable()
                // Do not track the query
                .AsNoTracking()
                // Obtain the currency where the abbreviation equals up
                .Where(c => c.Abbrv.Equals(abbreviation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                            && c.DeletedAt == null && c.IsEnabled)
                // Something here that will join the PartialCurrencyPair collection together and create one single Currency object.
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

> How do I come about it? Thank you so much in forward! Here's the
>   progress **I've made so far and it works, but I'm pretty LINQ has a beautiful way to make this better and optimised**:

```
var combinedCurrency = new Currency(_unitOfWork.GetRepository<Currency>()
                .GetQueryable()
                // Do not track the query
                .AsNoTracking()
                // Obtain the currency where the abbreviation equals up
                .Where(c => c.Abbrv.Equals(abbreviation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                            && c.DeletedAt == null && c.IsEnabled)
                .Include(c => c.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                .ThenInclude(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair)
                .ThenInclude(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests)
                .ThenInclude(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents)
                .ThenInclude(rc => rc.RequestComponentDatum)
                .ThenInclude(rcd => rcd.RcdHistoricItems)
                .ToList());


return new DetailedCurrencyResponse
                {
                    Name = combinedCurrency.Name,
                    Abbreviation = combinedCurrency.Abbrv,
                    LastUpdated = combinedCurrency.PartialCurrencyPairs
                        .Select(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair)
                        .SelectMany(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests)
                        .SelectMany(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents)
                        .OrderByDescending(rc => rc.ModifiedAt)
                        .FirstOrDefault()?
                        .ModifiedAt ?? DateTime.MinValue,
                    WeeklyAvgPrice = combinedCurrency.PartialCurrencyPairs
                        .Select(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair)
                        .Where(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests
                            .Any(cpr => cpr.DeletedAt == null && cpr.IsEnabled))
                        .SelectMany(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests)
                        .Where(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents
                            .Any(rc => rc.DeletedAt == null && rc.IsEnabled))
                        .SelectMany(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents
                            .Where(rc =>
                                rc.ComponentType.Equals(ComponentType.Ask) ||
                                rc.ComponentType.Equals(ComponentType.Bid)))
                        .Select(rc => rc.RequestComponentDatum)
                        .SelectMany(rcd => rcd.RcdHistoricItems
                            .Where(rcdhi => rcdhi.CreatedAt >
                                            DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))))
                        .Select(rcdhi => decimal.Parse(rcdhi.Value))
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        .Average(),
                    DailyVolume = combinedCurrency.PartialCurrencyPairs
                        .Select(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair)
                        .Where(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests
                            .Any(cpr => cpr.DeletedAt == null && cpr.IsEnabled))
                        .SelectMany(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests)
                        .Where(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents
                            .Any(rc => rc.DeletedAt == null && rc.IsEnabled))
                        .SelectMany(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents
                            .Where(rc => rc.ComponentType.Equals(ComponentType.VOLUME)
                                         && rc.DeletedAt == null && rc.IsEnabled))
                        .Select(rc => rc.RequestComponentDatum)
                        .SelectMany(rcd => rcd.RcdHistoricItems
                            .Where(rcdhi => rcdhi.CreatedAt >
                                            DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(24))))
                        .Select(rcdhi => decimal.Parse(rcdhi.Value))
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                        .Sum(),
                    Historical = combinedCurrency.PartialCurrencyPairs
                        .Select(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair)
                        .SelectMany(cp => cp.CurrencyPairRequests)
                        .SelectMany(cpr => cpr.RequestComponents)
                        .Where(rc => componentTypes != null 
                                     && componentTypes.Any()
                                     && componentTypes.Contains(rc.ComponentType)
                                     && rc.RequestComponentDatum != null
                                     && rc.RequestComponentDatum.IsEnabled 
                                     && rc.RequestComponentDatum.DeletedAt == null
                                     && rc.RequestComponentDatum.RcdHistoricItems
                                         .Any(rcdhi => rcdhi.DeletedAt == null &&
                                                       rcdhi.IsEnabled))
                        .ToDictionary(rc => rc.ComponentType,
                            rc => rc.RequestComponentDatum
                                .RcdHistoricItems
                                .Select(rcdhi => new ComponentHistoricalDatum
                                {
                                    CreatedAt = rcdhi.CreatedAt,
                                    Value = rcdhi.Value
                                })
                                .ToList())
                };
```

Here's the end result I want on that single object: A DetailedCurrencyResponse object.

```
public class DistinctiveCurrencyResponse
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

        public decimal WeeklyAvgPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal DailyVolume { get; set; }
    }
```

A historical datum is basically a kvp, where the Key (ComponentType) is an enum.

```
public class DetailedCurrencyResponse : DistinctiveCurrencyResponse
    {
        public Dictionary<ComponentType, List<ComponentHistoricalDatum>> Historical { get; set; }
    }

public class ComponentHistoricalDatum
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use string.Join("^", string[]).  Choose a character like ^ which is not part of any character in the strings you are trying to combine.

Comment: @jdweng How is that possible when my collection type is an object

Comment: @Nicholas `Something here that will join the PartialCurrencyPair collection together and create one single Currency object.` - What will be type of single currency object? a comma separated string? Also don't forget to include your `PartialCurrencyPair` model to the question.

Comment: You need a method to extract the properties of the object when the object is complex and use ToString() so all types are the same.

Comment: @TanvirArjel Done! Thank you! The single object is a DetailedCurrencyResponse object. Its now attached on the question.

Comment: @jdweng I don't quite get your answer, apologies for being unable to catch it.

Comment: string.Join(",",new string[] {x.Name,x.Abbrreviation,x.LastUpdated.ToString(),x.WeeklyAvgPrive.ToString(),x.DailyVolume.ToString()});

Comment: @jdweng Currently, I'm having issues at the SingleOrDefault() level. I've managed to successfully parse everything. I just need to find out what i'm missing that's supposed to be present before all the property declarations. Meaning, i need to merge the queryable to one Currency object first before i create this new DTO.

Comment: Why not FirstOrDefault()  If you have a List and want to convert to a single object just do a regular cast to an object : (object)query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189294/discussion-between-nicholas-and-jdweng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have outlined will attempt to return you a single Currency object, but given you are looking for any with a given abbreviation, if multiple currency objects share an abbreviation, the SingleOrDefault could error due to multiple returns.

It sounds like you want to define a structure to represent the currency pairs. That structure is *not* a Currency entity, but a different data representation. These are commonly referred to as ViewModels or DTOs. Once you've defined what you want to return, you can use `.Select()` to populate that from the Currency and applicable abbreviations.

For instance, if I create a CurrencySummaryDto which will have the currency ID, Abbrevation, and a string containing all of the applicable pairs:

```
public class CurrencySummaryDto
{
    public long CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Pairs { get; set;} 
}
```

... then the query...

```
var currencySummary = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Currency>()
    .GetQueryable()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(c => c.Abbrv.Equals(abbreviation, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        && c.DeletedAt == null && c.IsEnabled)
    .Select( c => new {
        c.Id,
        c.Abbrv,
        Pairs = c.PartialCurrencyPairs.Select(pc => pc.PairName).ToList() // Get names of pairs, or select another annonymous type for multiple properties you care about...
    }).ToList() // Alternatively, when intending for returning lots of data use Skip/Take for paginating or limiting resulting data.    
    .Select( c => new CurrencySummaryDto
    {
        CurrencyId = c.Id,
        Abbreviation = c.Abbrv,
        Pairs = string.Join(", ", c.Pairs)
    }).SingleOrDefault();
```

This is if you want to do something like combine data from the currency pairs into something like a string. If you're happy to leave them as a collection of simplified data, then the extra anonymous type and `.ToList()` are not required, just select directly into the Dto structure. This example combines the data into a string where `string.Join()` is not supported in EF expressions so we have to get our data out into objects to hand over to Linq2Object for the final mapping.

Edit: Ok, you're requirement/example just got a whole lot more complicated with the pair structure, but you should be able to leverage this into the query rather than selecting the entire graph of entities by moving the selection of those values up into the main query... However...

Given the complexity of the data relationships, the approach I would recommend using since this would be assumed to be a read-only result, would be to construct a View in the database to flatten these averages and totals, then bind a simplified entity to this view rather than attempting to manage this with EF Linq. I believe it can be done with linq, but it will be quite onerous to look at, and a view-based summary entity would be a lot cleaner while keeping the execution of this logic to be executed in the database.

Comment: Hey there! You're really super close! It's just that with regards to how PartialCurrencyPairs work, I didn't give you enough information to understand why it is structured like that. I've updated my question with more details that I believe will be adequate for you to see how i can come about to obtaining the answer I'm looking for!

Comment: Edited my response. I think that you can leverage EF Linq if you really want to, but for a summary result like that I would recommend using a DB View to flatten those results, then bind a simple entity across the view.